# Blur event handling

Tags: javascript, angular, blur, onblur

I have a blur function to check if an input must contain an Alphabet. I trigger a function on the blur event to check for the validation. 
I have a Next button in my footer component which Navigates me to the next page.

Now if I add an invalid input (ex: 123) and then directly click on the Next button (without tabbing out of the input field), I get redirected instead of showing the field level Validation.

Can someone please help me on how to tackle this scenario using JavaScript?

**My Html Code snippet**

```
<mat-form-field>
      <input autocomplete="offf" matInput [formControlName]="'lastName'" maxlength="30" 
       [placeholder]="'Last Name'" 
      (blur)="checkNameValidation($event , 'lastName')"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

**My ts file function**

```
checkNameValidation(event , element: string) {
var containsAlphabet = /[a-zA-Z]/.test(event.target.value);
if(!containsAlphabet) {
  this.myForm.get(element).setErrors({'invalid': true});
}
}
```

Comment: why are not using patter validation with reactive form?

Comment: Why don't you use `(change)`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

- disabling the submit button until all form fields have passed
- returning false for onSubmit of the form if any of the
  form fields have failed validation

Comment: The submit button that I have in my project is a part of the footer, for which I have a separate project and I get that footer using a tgz file. 

So I can not disable the Next button. 

I am actually returning false in case of a failed validation. But in this case, the validation and the click on the next functionality happen simultaneously and hence it takes me to the next page before actually throwing a validation.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular scenario you are supposed to use keydown event. Which will help you to capture all keyboard which was happening on that field.

Use below link for further reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event

Comment: I can use a keydown event but it is not working when I paste something in that input field. I can unfortunately not stop the paste event. :/

Comment: If you are performing copy and paste using keyboard event it will work. If you are performing with mouse event then you should have both keyboard and mouse event together